# Boostrap navbar-toggler not visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When using the following code, I run into a problem where the navbar-toggler-icon is not visible(still works if you click where the button is). I modified the color pretty much all aspects of the navbar, but I'm not too sure what is causing the problem.

HTML

```css
 .navbar {
        font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
        background-color: #2f3b59;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text a {
        color: #4db7fe;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text a:hover,
    .navbar .navbar-text a:focus {
        color: #4db7fe; 
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: .25rem;
        margin: 0 0.25em;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-toggler {
        border-color: #2f3b59;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-toggler:hover,
    .navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
        background-color: #2f3b59;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Freelance NZ</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav" aria-controls="mainNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.navbar {
        font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
        background-color: #2f3b59;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text a {
        color: #4db7fe;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text a:hover,
    .navbar .navbar-text a:focus {
        color: #4db7fe; 
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: .25rem;
        margin: 0 0.25em;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-toggler {
        border-color: #ffc107;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-toggler:hover,
    .navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
        background-color: #ffc107;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
     
     
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Freelance NZ</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler text-white" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav" aria-controls="mainNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="material-icons">menu</span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .navbar {
        font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
        background-color: #2f3b59;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text a {
        color: #4db7fe;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-text a:hover,
    .navbar .navbar-text a:focus {
        color: #4db7fe; 
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: .25rem;
        margin: 0 0.25em;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-toggler {
        border-color: #2f3b59;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-toggler:hover,
    .navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
        background-color: #2f3b59;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Freelance NZ</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav" aria-controls="mainNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```